# Prove $(X,d)$ is a metric space where $|X| < |\mathbb{R}|$, then $X$ is zero-dimensional.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cantor-set

Can I please receive help with part (ii) of this problem? I have no clue how to solve it. It is from Munkree's topology book. Thank you!
$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}  
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}$

A topological space $X$ is zero-dimensional if it has a basis $B$ consisting of open sets which are simultaneously closed.

For some reason, my solution is not posting, so I will try later to repost it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For (i) use the form that is given: $C=\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ which is a product of zero-dimensional spaces (a discrete space is of course zero-dimensional), and as such zero-dimensional too (use the standard base for a product where all non-trivial open sets come from a chosen clopen base in each factor space).

(ii) For any $x$, and any $r>0$, consider the function $f(y)=d(x,y): X \to \Bbb R$. $f[X]$ has size $< |\Bbb R|$ too, so cannot contain $(0,r)$ which has size continuum. So for some $0 < s < r$, the value $d(x,y)=s$ cannot occur for any $y$, which implies that $B(x,s)=\overline{B(x,s)} \subseteq B(x,r)$ and we have a clopen set inside every open ball of the same centre, which tells us $X$ is zero-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you Henno for the help. I did not realize my solution for (i) was wrong as well. I will rethink this now.

Comment: This gives a roundabout proof that the Cantor set is uncountable.

Comment: @ChrisCuster not quite: that $C$ is in bijection with $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ (and it's even a homeomorphism) is the standard proof that $C$ has size $\|\Bbb R|$, so uncountable. Moreover, a set can be of size smaller than continuum and uncountable (in ZFC we cannot exclude that) and we can have zero-dimensional spaces of any cardinality. In ZFC we see $|C| = |\Bbb R|$ and this says nothing about zero-dimensionality at all.

Comment: My point should have been that since the dimension of the Cantor set, $\ln2/\ln3$, is greater than zero, it must have cardinality  of the continuum, by part $(ii)$.  Which, as you note, is different from saying it is uncountable, by CH.

Comment: @ChrisCuster the *fractal* dimension is that value, not the topological dimension ! Those are very different things. Cantor set has dimension $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.